# Help needed for wxWidgets - DialogBlocks

Tags: gcc, wxwidgets

I'm using DialogBlocks to build a dialog and got the errors below

> *** g++ i386: No such file or directory
>   *** cclplus: error: unrecognized command line option *-arch"*
>    make * [GCCRelease/AdvancedControls:0]

I really don't know what does that mean. By the way, I'm a new learner on this field, any effort is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

T

Comment: looks to me like the c++ compiler is complaining ..

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you tried to pass the option "-arch i386" to g++ which is a Mac-only option.

Presumably you're building on Linux? I don't know anything about DialogBlocks or your build process so I can't say more but maybe that'll give enough to work it out.